# update nested json value in react forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my json

```
this.state = {
            name: '',
            subCatagory: [{ name: '', price: '', customize: [] }],
        };
```

my map function

```
 {this.state.subCatagory.map((subCatagory, idx) => (
                        <div className="subCatagory" key={idx}>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                placeholder={`Enter Dish  #${idx + 1} name`}
                                value={subCatagory.name}
                                onChange={this.handlesubCatagoryNameChange(idx)}
                            />
                            <input
                                type="number"
                                placeholder={`subCatagory #${idx + 1} price`}
                                value={subCatagory.price}
                                onChange={this.handlesubCatagoryPriceChange(idx)}
                            />
                            <button
                                type="button"
                                onClick={this.handleRemovesubCatagory(idx)}
                                className="small"
                            >
                                Delete
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" onClick={this.addNewCust(idx)} className="small">
                                is cust availble?
                            </button>
                            {subCatagory.customize.map((gj, f) => (
                                <div key={f}>
                                    <input
                                        type="text"
                                        placeholder={`subCatagory #${f + 1} price`}
                                        value={gj.name}
                                        key={gj.key}
                                        onChange={this._pushvaluesto_customize(f)}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    ))}
```

i have two .map functions one for subCatagory and then other for customize ., the above code will does this

when i click the `onClick={this.handleAddsubCatagory}` a new array will push to this.state as `name: '',subCatagory: [{ name: '', price: '', customize: [] }],`

on every text change in name and price in subCatagory `onChange={this.handlesubCatagoryNameChange(idx)}` and then `onChange={this.handlesubCatagoryPriceChange(idx)}` it will update the `subCatagory: [{ name: '', price: '', customize: [] }],` json ., but i don't know how to update the field values for customize which was nested inside the subCatagory.,

my code for updating in  subCatagory

```
handlesubCatagoryNameChange = idx => evt => {
        const subCatagory = this.state.subCatagory.map((subCatagory, sidx) => {
            if (idx !== sidx) return subCatagory;
            return { ...subCatagory, name: evt.target.value };
        });

        this.setState({ subCatagory: subCatagory });
    };
```

how to update nested json using map in react forms

my gist https://gist.github.com/gjgit/78bde9415b889331c9d4bfa52e4945ad

Answer (score 2):

If already have access to the index of the element, then element value directly can be updated as shown below, the map function will unnecessarily loop through the array.
  Here  `custIdx` is the index of the element of the customize array which needs to be updated

```
handlesubCatagoryChange = (idx, property, custIdx) => evt => {
    const subCatagory = this.state.subCatagory
    property != 'customize'? subCategory[idx][property] = evt.target.value : subCategory[idx][property][custIdx] = evt.target.value

    this.setState({ subCatagory: subCatagory });
};
```

Comment: can elaborate or share code by gist or something ., it will helpful for me

Comment: i am getting undefined error ` Line 61:  'customize' is not defined    no-undef
  Line 61:  'subCategory' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 61:  'subCategory' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: customize should be a string

Comment: thank you ., but stil i get `  Line 60:  "subCategory" is not defined  no-undef` error

Comment: this.state.subCatagory is not defined?

Comment: not sure but have you bind handlesubCatagoryChange function with component like:

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.handlesubCatagoryChange = this.handlesubCatagoryChange.bind(this)
}`

Comment: `constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
   name: '',
   subCatagory: [{ name: '', price: '', customize: [] }],
  };
 }`

my constructor looks like this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171573/discussion-between-bhavya-bharti-and-user-3535).